# When display:flex, flex-direction:column is applied to the parent element, the height of the child element with position:relative becomes 0

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, emotion

For vertical alignment, display:flex and flex-direction:column were applied, but when the child elements exceed the modal height of 40rem, the height of the ImageWrapper is adjusted to 0 even if overflow-y:scroll is applied. Anyone know about the cause?

```
const ModalWrapper = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 10;
`


const Modal = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 40rem;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
`

const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
`

const GalleryDetail: React.FC<{
  setOpen: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
}> = ({ setOpen }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute('style', 'overflow: hidden')
    return () => document.body.setAttribute('style', 'overflow: auto')
  }, [])

  return (
    <ModalWrapper>
      <Modal>
        <ImageWrapper>
          <Image src="/image60.png" alt="gallery detail" fill />
        </ImageWrapper>
         /* Here are the child elements */
      <Modal>
    <ModalWrapper>
)}

export default GalleryDetail
```

I solved the problem by removing the flex property, but I would be very grateful if you could tell me about the cause of the problem.